# Software center is broken

Tags: apt, software-center

When I started installing the Humble Indie Bundle 5 games the software center stopped working and now I get this error.

Packages cannot be installed or removed, click here to repair. Which fails and gives these results.

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 255502 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libqtcore4:i386 (from .../libqtcore4_4%3a4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libqtcore4_4%3a4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 conffile './etc/xdg/Trolltech.conf' is not in sync with other instances of the same package
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libqtcore4_4%3a4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1_i386.deb
Error in function: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqtgui4:i386:
 libqtgui4:i386 depends on libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqtcore4:i386 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing libqtgui4:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-sql:i386:
 libqt4-sql:i386 depends on libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqtcore4:i386 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-sql:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ia32-libs-multiarch:i386:
 ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 depends on libqt4-sql; however:
  Package libqt4-sql:i386 is not configured yet.
 ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 depends on libqtcore4; however:
  Package libqtcore4:i386 is not installed.
 ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 depends on libqtgui4; however:
  Package libqtgui4:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-declarative:i386:
 libqt4-declarative:i386 depends on libqt4-sql (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqt4-sql:i386 is not configured yet.
 libqt4-declarative:i386 depends on libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqtcore4:i386 is not installed.
 libqt4-declarative:i386 depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqtgui4:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-declarative:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-svg:i386:
 libqt4-svg:i386 depends on libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqtcore4:i386 is not installed.
 libqt4-svg:i386 depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqtgui4:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-svg:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-network:i386:
 libqt4-network:i386 depends on libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqtcore4:i386 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-network:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-sql-mysql:i386:
 libqt4-sql-mysql:i386 depends on libqt4-sql (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqt4-sql:i386 is not configured yet.
 libqt4-sql-mysql:i386 depends on libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqtcore4:i386 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-sql-mysql:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-script:i386:
 libqt4-script:i386 depends on libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqtcore4:i386 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-script:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-dbus:i386:
 libqt4-dbus:i386 depends on libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqtcore4:i386 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-dbus:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-opengl:i386:
 libqt4-opengl:i386 depends on libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqtcore4:i386 is not installed.
 libqt4-opengl:i386 depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqtgui4:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-opengl:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqtwebkit4:i386:
 libqtwebkit4:i386 depends on libqt4-network (>= 4:4.8.0~); however:
  Package libqt4-network:i386 is not configured yet.
 libqtwebkit4:i386 depends on libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0~); however:
  Package libqtcore4:i386 is not installed.
 libqtwebkit4:i386 depends on libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0); however:
  Package libqtgui4:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqtwebkit4:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-designer:i386:
 libqt4-designer:i386 depends on libqt4-script (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqt4-script:i386 is not configured yet.
 libqt4-designer:i386 depends on libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqtcore4:i386 is not installed.
 libqt4-designer:i386 depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqtgui4:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-designer:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lonesurvivor-bin:i386:
 lonesurvivor-bin:i386 depends on ia32-libs-multiarch; however:
  Package ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing lonesurvivor-bin:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lonesurvivor:
 lonesurvivor depends on lonesurvivor-bin (= 1.11d-0ubuntu5); however:
  Package lonesurvivor-bin is not installed.
  Package lonesurvivor-bin:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing lonesurvivor (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-scripttools:i386:
 libqt4-scripttools:i386 depends on libqt4-script (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqt4-script:i386 is not configured yet.
 libqt4-scripttools:i386 depends on libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqtcore4:i386 is not installed.
 libqt4-scripttools:i386 depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqtgui4:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-scripttools:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-qt3support:i386:
 libqt4-qt3support:i386 depends on libqt4-designer (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqt4-designer:i386 is not configured yet.
 libqt4-qt3support:i386 depends on libqt4-network (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqt4-network:i386 is not configured yet.
 libqt4-qt3support:i386 depends on libqt4-sql (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqt4-sql:i386 is not configured yet.
 libqt4-qt3support:i386 depends on libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqtcore4:i386 is not installed.
 libqt4-qt3support:i386 depends on libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqtgui4:i386 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-qt3support:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-xml:i386:
 libqt4-xml:i386 depends on libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqtcore4:i386 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-xml:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-test:i386:
 libqt4-test:i386 depends on libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqtcore4:i386 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-test:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386:
 libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 depends on libqt4-network (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqt4-network:i386 is not configured yet.
 libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 depends on libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1); however:
  Package libqtcore4:i386 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

I couldn't get the apt-get update or upgrade to work either so I shut off the repositories and updated / upgraded one at a time without any problems. But that didn't fix the Software Center.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

ADDED UPDATE

I've tried to install `aptitude` using `dpkg` but can't. I have also tried

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo dpkg --configure -a --force-all
```

and the -f options.

Though I believe this is where my problem is originating:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libqtcore4:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libqtcore4:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2,061 kB of archives.
After this operation, 9,041 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 255526 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libqtcore4:i386 (from .../libqtcore4_4%3a4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libqtcore4_4%3a4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 conffile './etc/xdg/Trolltech.conf' is not in sync with other instances of the same package
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libqtcore4_4%3a4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I hope this helps narrow it down some.

SECOND UPDATE

`sudo apt-get --reinstall install software-center -f`

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-dbus:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-declarative:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-designer:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-network:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-opengl:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-qt3support:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-script:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-scripttools:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-sql:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-sql-mysql:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-svg:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-test:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-xml:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqtgui4:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (= 4:4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libqtwebkit4:i386 : Depends: libqtcore4:i386 (>= 4:4.8.0~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

`sudo apt-get -f install` doesn't work either.

Complete output of terminal for [step 5 of this procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure#Step_5) can be found here:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/1066192/

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it myself. Took about 8 hours of playing around.

I went into the software center package lists and deleted the info for Lone Survivor and Psychonaughts (the problems) and did sudo apt-get -f install. Then I re-installed the libcore4 files.

But now that it is fixed I don't even want to try and download the Humble Bundle 5 again.

Comment: Hmm.  Sorry to hear that -- I haven't had serious issues with any of the humble bundle games, once software center finally synced up.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command: `sudo aptitude reinstall software-center`

Comment: I don't have aptitude installed. I tried to install the .deb using dpkg and it says it depends on libcore4i386 which is my problem.

Comment: @Colin You can use `sudo apt-get --reinstall install software-center` instead.

Comment: It doesn't work, I posted the error above.